# WP Google Fonts question

Tags: plugins

I'm using Google Webfonts on my Wordpress site (WP Google Fonts plugin) and was wondering whether those fonts are stored on Google server or are uploaded from the server my website is on?

I love some of those fonts, but in my case no love could stand the test of few hundred kilobytes each time someone visits my website.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google web fonts are saved on google's servers not your's, when you apply a font to your site the stylesheet link will be included in your document's head section, the stylesheet and font will be directly downloaded to client's (visitor) browser, there is nothing any bandwidth usage from your server for the google web font.

oh yes just a few bytes, which are a line of code in your document's head section to include a link to css file.

read more [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/technical_considerations)

Comment: Anjum is correct but there is the bandwidth transfer of the actual font file and the time it takes for that request and response to go back and forth from Google to your site.  It can be a noticeable delay.  You can check it with a site like webpagetest.org to see the amount of time it takes.  Check the waterfall image for that asset.

Comment: @marty asker want to know about their server's bandwidth usage, the site loading time is another issue which can be resolved or minimize using less and small (in file size) fonts, 50-100 kb are the worth of look and feel.